# When creating a RAR file through CMD am getting "Access is denied"

Tags: cmd, rar

I have a set of files in my system which am creating a RAR file by using a task scheduler and executing a bat file.
This is my bat file

```
TITLE Covert_To_war
cd D:\RarFolder\Current
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -idq -r -y "Current" "E:\Folder1\backup"
```

When I execute this bat file alone this function works properly and the Rar file is created. However when I run this from a task scheduler. This throws off an error

Cannot create Current.rar
Access is denied

When I tried to compare the two procedures I found out that the first line in the bat file

```
cd D:\RarFolder\Current
```

works when I execute it alone as a bat file. However, when I run it from a task scheduler that line is not executing and the directory hasn't been changed. Can anyone help me out here? Why is the Cd command not working when I execute it from a task scheduler and why does it say Cannot create Current.rar and access is denied.
enter code here

Comment: Change `cd D:\RarFolder\Current` to `cd /D "D:\RarFolder\Current"` to change the drive as well…

Comment: You could also discard the batch file and configure the scheduled task to run `"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"` with the arguments `a -ep1 -idq -r -y "D:\RarFolder\Current\Current.rar" "E:\Folder1\backup"` as there is no need to run `cmd.exe` to just run `rar.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to list your Task Scheduler settings. If they are anything other than *Only Run When User Logged On* then the script won't have access to mapped drives by drive letter as drive letters are mapped by security token. You may use UNC `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. In the windows task scheduler under actions, I just configured the "start in" field to point out the directory I want the operations to be done.
I had got the access denied error because the first line "CD.." command hadn't been carried out.